# C# Text gets overwritten between runs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamwriter

I have a streamwriter that writes some words to a text file. It prints one word on every line, but if I stop the application and start it again The old words disappear and only the new ones are there. How do make it so that the words don't get overwritten?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ListScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField word;
    StreamWriter s;

    void Start() {
        s = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.txt");
    }

    public void NewList() {
       if(word != null) { 
           print(Application.persistentDataPath);
           s.WriteLine(s.NewLine + word.text);
           s.Flush();
       }
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
        s.Close();
        Debug.Log("I was here");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know.  How could I know without seeing your code?

Comment: use `new StreamWriter( "path", true)` to open it for appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `StreamWriter` which will overwrite the file everytime.

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share. If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

You could simply use [`File.AppendAllText(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your purpose. In this case you won't even need to use the `StreamWriter`.

You can change your code to

```
if (word != null) { 
    print(Application.persistentDataPath);
    File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.txt", s.NewLine + word.text);
}
```

So your complete code would look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ListScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField word;

    void Start() {
    }

    public void NewList() {
       if (word != null) { 
           print(Application.persistentDataPath);
           File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.txt", s.NewLine + word.text);
       }
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
        Debug.Log("I was here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to append text to the end of the file instead of starting over. Here is more information on [File.AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You can't answer the question yet.  It's too vague at this point.

Comment: What? Is there some etiquette rule that I'm breaking?

Comment: No.  I'm just saying shot-in-the-dark answers are not acceptable.

Comment: It's not a shot in the dark. The OP is sending text into a txt [file]. On subsequent runs of the program, the text is getting overwritten. Clearly he means to append.

Comment: The OP didn't say text *file*...among other things.

Comment: @roryap It's fairly reasonable to assume it's a text file based on _txt_ and the use of a _streamwriter_

Comment: @juharr -- sure, I'm just pointing out how it can be dangerous to assume and jump the gun by answering before getting clarification on a vague question.

Comment: @juharr That is my point. I felt like it was a safe assumption.

Comment: IMHO - can be dangerous, but this is a valid assumption and not worth a downvote for the assumption...

Comment: @roryap and squillman, Point taken. I will slow down in the future.

Comment: To me the bigger deal was whether using `File.AppendText` would make sense for the OP without seeing the code first.

Comment: I'm only here to watch the fight

Answer (score -1):

You used StreamWriter(string path) constructor to access your file.

[If you look up in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that if "path" is a file, and the file exists, it will be overwritten.

One way to solve this is to open a FileStream in File.Append mode. In this instance, you don't need to use a StreamWriter at all. You'll need to ensure that the FileStream is properly disposed when you're done with it to prevent leaking resources.